# Map fundamental type to struct using CallConvMemberFunction

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following C++ code:

```cpp
struct IFoo
{
    virtual int __stdcall GetValue1(int value) = 0;
    virtual int __stdcall GetValue2(int value) = 0;
};

struct Foo : IFoo
{
    int __stdcall GetValue1(int value) override
    {
        return value + 1;
    }

    int __stdcall GetValue2(int value) override
    {
        return value + 1;
    }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CreateObject(IFoo** ptr)
{
    *ptr = new Foo;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void FreeObject(IFoo* ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
}
```

And C#:

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: DisableRuntimeMarshalling]

struct Result
{
    public readonly int value;

    public Result(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

unsafe struct IFoo : IFoo.Interface
{
    public readonly Vtbl<IFoo>* lpVtbl;

    public int GetValue1(int value)
    {
        return lpVtbl->GetValue1((IFoo*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref this), value);
    }

    public Result GetValue2(int value)
    {
        return lpVtbl->GetValue2((IFoo*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref this), value);
    }

    public interface Interface
    {
        int GetValue1(int value);
        Result GetValue2(int value);
    }

    public struct Vtbl<TSelf>
        where TSelf : unmanaged, Interface
    {
        public delegate* unmanaged[Stdcall, MemberFunction]<TSelf*, int, int> GetValue1;
        public delegate* unmanaged[Stdcall, MemberFunction]<TSelf*, int, Result> GetValue2;
    }
}

unsafe partial class Program
{
    [LibraryImport("CppLibrary")]
    private static partial void CreateObject(IFoo** ptr);

    [LibraryImport("CppLibrary")]
    private static partial void FreeObject(IFoo* ptr);

    public void Run()
    {
        IFoo* ptr;
        CreateObject(&ptr);
        Console.WriteLine(ptr->GetValue1(3));
        Console.WriteLine(ptr->GetValue2(3).value);
        FreeObject(ptr);
    }
}
```

I expect to see `4 4` in output but I see `4 0`. If I replace `Result` with `int` everything works fine. Also removing `MemberFunction` fixes the problem. I want to get a better understanding as to why this happens. I thought that `Result` struct is blittable and basically can be placed instead of the same sized type. Obviously, I'm getting it wrong. Can someone please explain to me why this behavior occurs and is there a way to keep `Result` as a return type and having `MemberFunction` at the same time?